# NPM throws error "couldn't read dependencies"?

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM throws error "couldn't read dependencies"

```
yiffbook:home yiff$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/home/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Could you help me fix this?

Comment: The answer is right in your post: "npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Try to update npm,It works for me**

```
[sudo] npm install -g npm
```

for more info use this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server):

Comment: Its working but updating all the libraries when i type **npm install express**

Answer (score 12):

You are running npm install from /home.It tries to search for package.json in /home.Where is your node.js project?Example if its in C:\nodeproject\pasty.Then go to C:\nodeproject\pasty(the package.json will be there) and then do the npm install

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like your issue, but for me this was caused by an invalid version number in package.json (had to change 2.4 to 2.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes because of the old version of `npm` available. 
Please update your `npm` to the latest version; this may solve your problem. If it doesn't, you can try installing externally relevant packages with version, for example:

```
  npm install sqlite3.
```